# How to remove special character and numbers from the python dataframe?

Tags: pandas, dataframe

i have  a excel sheet as shown below

```
Input  out1  out2 out3 out4 out5 

in1    x      x   x     o    x 

in2    x      .         c     v 

in3    3     ?                x

in4     x          /
```

I will have to remove numbers and special characters , characters other than x and o from the excel sheet.

my Desired output is as shown below.

```
Input  out1  out2 out3 out4 out5 

in1    x    x     x     o    x

in2    x            

in3                          x     

in4    x
```

Answer (score 0):

After loading the dataset into Python:

```
import pandas as pd

data = {
    'Input': ['in1', 'in2', 'in3', 'in4'],
    'out1': ['x', 'x', '3', 'x'],
    'out2': ['x', '.', '?', ''],
    'out3': ['x', 'c', '', '/'],
    'out4': ['o', 'v', 'x', ''],
    'out5': ['x', '', '', '']
}

df = pd.DataFrame(data)

df.applymap(lambda x: x if x in ['x', 'o'] else "")

# Output:
  Input out1 out2 out3 out4 out5
0          x    x    x    o    x
1          x                    
2                         x     
3          x
```

This is assuming you want the missing values to be "", and not NA or NaN or None.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way would be to use [`pandas.DataFrame.replace`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.replace.html)

```
df.replace('[^xo]', '', regex=True)
```

Output

```
  Input out1 out2 out3 out4 out5
0          x    x    x    o    x
1          x                    
2                         x     
3          x
```

Answer (score 0):

You can run the following to make all kind of special chars, not only that you have encountered, replaced with an empty string.

```
df.replace('[@_!#$%^&*()<>?/\|}{~:]','',regex=True,inplace=True)
```